# The condition doesn't seem to work. (while (dAmount != (2*dbAmount))) Also, the first calculation isn't correct o.O

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

My friend and I are learning C++, and we can't seem to get this program running as it should be. So basically, what we are now attempting, is a tasks that requires us to script a program in which the user is asked two variables. One of these variables is a tax percentage (in the form of 1.X) and the other is any positive, real number. Now what it is we need to know, is why our condition isn't prompting? We would really appreciate an answer to our question. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        double dTax;
        double dbAmount;
        double dAmount;
        cout << "Tax? (In the form of 1.05)" << endl;
        cin >> dTax;
        cout << "Amount?" << endl;
        cin >> dbAmount;
        cout << dbAmount << " is the amount without taxes incalculated." << endl;
        dAmount = (dbAmount*dTax);
        while (dAmount != (2*dbAmount))
        {
            dAmount = (dAmount*dTax);
            cout << dAmount << " is the next amount, with taxes incalculated." << endl;
            break;
        }
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `<`, not `!=`. Multiplying by 1.05 or whatever each time will not always land on two times the original, and there is the matter of floating-point error as well. Also, you might want to change the name of the function, as global names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Is is complete code, where is `main()`.

Comment: Oh, well, I need the the program to keep on calculating, until the value of the newly formed dAmount is twice as large as the first input for dbAmount. :)

Comment: When you ponder what chris' comment is all about, get something to drink, preferably of an alcoholic nature, and spend some time reading [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to get the gore-filled details on everything you never wanted to know about floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm writing this the code does not have a `main` function.

You need a `main` function, like

```
int main()
{
    // my main program statements
}
```

Slightly oversimplified, that's where the program execution starts.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the fast response, but actually we changed the entry point in the linker options. We changed it to _7z. Hence the
    int _7z()
    {
    } serves as int main(){}. Thanks nonetheless. :)

Comment: @7zS2: you really don't want to do that. the entry point you specify to the linker is not `main` or an alternative. it's the machine code level entry point which initializes things (including the standard library's i/o streams) and *calls* `main`. so don't do that. do have a `main`.

Comment: @7zS2, Was that in the book? Or `return -7;`? Both are pretty pointless. The latter typically implies you had an error.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks. Will change it back to its original.